# How to calculate time between 2 points

Tags: c#, datetime

I have `Wireshark` file with several `packets` inside.
From user and via `command line arguments` i get from the user 2 Arguments:
1. `Number of packet to add`.
2. `delay`.

Now after the first `packet` i need to add number of `packets` that the user specify and the delay between this `packets` need to be the `delay` value but this delay need to divided between all the `packets`.

For example:
The user send the numbers `150` and `8` so after the first `packet` i need to add another 149 new `packets` (should be 250 packets total) and the delay between all this `packets` need to be 8 `milliseconds`.
From this first packet i have this `timestamp` property (`DateTime` object)
So for each `timestamp` i need to add 53.33 `microseconds`.

So this is my function that gets the first `packet`:

int numberOfpackets;
int delay;

```
private static DateTime GetNewTimeStamp(packet packet)
{
    DateTime newTimeStamp = packet.timeStamp;
}
```

How can i add build new `timestamp` (the time not matter only the delay) according this 2 arguments from the user ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DateTime.Add(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method to return a new DateTime object that has the specified offset to the current instance.

For the TimeSpan object, you will need to specify the amount of time in Ticks, since the resolution of the other constructors only goes down to milliseconds.
You can use [`TimeSpan.FromTicks(Long)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks(v=vs.110).aspx) to get such a TimeSpan, where 1 tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds.

Comment: But how can i determine the amount of milliseconds/microseconds,nanoseconds between each packet ?

Comment: You divide the total delay by the number of packages, like you did in your opening post? Just convert the user's millisecond delay to nanoseconds first and then divide the result by 100 to get the required amount of ticks. I don't see the problem.